# Channel does not show entries on specific template site

Tags: channel-entries, templates, template-manager

I have a very weird behaviour: One of my channels does not show any entries on one specific template site.

I use the following EE tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery_slider" category="6" limit="1"}test output{/exp}
```

When I use this code in the one specific template, it does not show `test output`. I made sure, that I have content in the channel with the category: I used the tag within another template, where the `test output` is shown as expected.

In the problematic template I use another channel, which is showing its content correctly.

I have no idea what could lead to this behaviour as both templates are nearly identical.

- I don't use the channel within the other channel
- both templates (the working and the non working template) use each two different channels
- In one template the channel `gallery_slider` outputs content
- In one template the channel `gallery_slider` does not output content
- both templates have a url defined via template route manager

**Any ideas, what could lead to the missing content?**

Comment: Try adding dynamic="no" to your parameters.

Comment: where do i do that? to which parameter? of the channel or the category?

Comment: {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery_slider" category="6" limit="1" dynamic="no"}

Comment: Oh cool, that works, why is that? I can't find a documentation to dynamic="no". Thank you, Brandon!

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer and response to below if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `dynamic="no"` to your parameters like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery_slider" category="6" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
    test output
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

ExpressionEngine tries to determine the `entry_id` or `url_title` by itself, and if that id isn't part of that channel it won't show anything.

[Here's a link](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) to the docs.